# selecting values from single value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to make a small SQL script that is going to print all the values that are associated with that value.

For example, if I have this table:

```
1    |    1
1    |    2
1    |    3
2    |    1
2    |    2
3    |    1
4    |    2
```

How can I get listing that shows me something like this:

```
1| 1 2 3
2| 1 2
3| 1
4| 2
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have tried using group by and having but the probelm is that i get only the listing of the first row. I don#t have any idea how to write out second row

Comment: Do you want this in a list or do you want those values in separate columns?  It's not clear from your desired output.

Comment: I just want to use select order that will show me inside relation inside the table

Comment: I want the to be in a single column

Answer (score 1):

```
select col_1,
       listagg(col_2, ' ') within group (order by col_2) as all_values
from the_table
group by col_1
order by col_1;
```